# KVO - observe() changeHandler does not provide callback for certain properties

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working on a drag-and-drop implementation for `UICollectionView` and I'm trying to observe its '[hasActiveDrag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/2897415-hasactivedrag)' property to handle respective passive changes when a drag ends/fails.

Not sure if I'm missing something trivial but this particular property (and a few related properties) does not return any callbacks in `changeHandler` despite the value changes.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
dragSessionObserver = self.myCollectionView.observe(\.hasActiveDrag, options: [.new, .initial], changeHandler: { (cv, change) in
    //blah blah blah
})
```

**And when I try this with other properties, it works as intended**...

**P.S.**

Why observe when I've got delegate provisions?

The delegate does not get called when a session fails/cancels. The one way that I know to capture failed sessions is through the cell's `dragStateDidChange` function, which also gets called during reuse and reload. Hence, I cannot solely rely on it for only for failure callbacks. So, I've decided to opt for KVO. Would really appreciate a better way to capture session failures/cancellations

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having similar issues!

Comment: @simonthumper Nope, using the default drag-drop provision felt unnecessarily complicated for a peculiar use-case that I had to achieve. So I ended up writing something similar myself